# how to find correct model item from list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

sub_employee is class of database context. IM.getAvailableList() return int array from WSDL. I want to find list of model Items which has SE_ID equals to int array item.below action method only retrieve SE_ID.

```
public ActionResult Ataxi()
    {
        var alist = IM.getAvailableList().Select(x => new sub_employee { SE_ID = x }).ToList();
        return View(alist);
    }
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem. thank you

Comment: Do you want something like: 
`var alist = IM.getAvailableList().Where(x => x.SE_ID == id}).ToList();` ?

Comment: that is not what want. I want list of sub_employees who are available in getAvailable()method

Comment: Try this `var alist = IM.getAvailableList().Where(x => x.SE_ID == id}).Select(y=>y.sub_employees).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Ataxi(int id)
 {
    var alist = IM.getAvailableList().Select(x => new sub_employee { SE_ID = id}).ToList();
    return View(alist);
    }
```